# cx_Freeze unable to freeze tkinter GUI application on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter, cx-freeze

I have a python script with a Tkinter GUI which works fine on both Windows and Ubuntu. I can successfully freeze it with cx_Freeze on Windows. But when I freeze the script on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the executable is unable to load Tkinter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slarag/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 120, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "/home/slarag/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 16, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    /usr/share/tcl8.5 /home/slarag/pydummy/build/lib/tcl8.5 /home/slarag/pydummy/lib/tcl8.5 /home/slarag/pydummy/build/library /home/slarag/pydummy/library /home/slarag/pydummy/tcl8.5.13/library /home/slarag/tcl8.5.13/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I'm using Python 3.10.4 in a virtual environment and the following packages:

```
cx-Freeze==6.11.1
packaging==21.3
patchelf==0.14.5.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
```

The issue is reproducible with a very simple script:

**main.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
build_options = {'packages': ['tkinter'], 'excludes': [], 'includes': ['tkinter']}

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('main.py', base=base, target_name = 'pydummy')
]

setup(name='pydummy',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables = executables)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The cx_freeze bundle on linux has a precompiled shared libraries located under site-packages/cx_freeze/bases as opposed to the windows and macos bundle. I have the same experience. Basically these libraries are for tk8.5 where python3.10 has tk8.6

So they are not compatible at all.

The hook for specifying tkinter libraries in the tutorial are also only applicable at windows as written on hooks.py

What i did is to create a hook for ubuntu to manually find the right tcl and tk libraries and also replace the _tkinter*.so file with the installed one on my system.

Also have to manually include the tcl and tkinter libraries

1. First step:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFHed.png) update tkinter hook in hooks.py

Then add the environ variables in your setup file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTh2U.jpg)

2. Second step is:
   [Update setup files include_files options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv9XC.jpg)
3. Last is make sure u update the so file from your installed python
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97goE.png)

I was able to compile my application.